# Unity: how do I make an input only available to the code?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a simple function attached to a button. I then decided to change it by adding an input. The problem is that the function won’t run unless I specify the input in Unity via the inspector. I don’t want to do that because it will affect the function and I have already changed it inside. I already set the input when I run the function so there’s no need to set it again in Unity; this is a problem because the input is going to be different depending on different scenarios. How can I overcome this?

```
public void Eruption(string biome)
{
    if (biome == “sea”) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** As of the current version of Unity, this answer is outdated. I posted another answer which applies to Unity Version 2018.3 and later. But I will leave this answer here for those who don't dare to convert their project yet.

Unfortunately you can not tell Unity buttons to call methods with parameters. If you want different buttons to call the same method with different parameters, you will have to take one of several possible workarounds:

Option 1: Create a wrapper-method for each one which takes no arguments and then calls the method you want with the correct argument:

```
public void ErruptionAtSea()
{
    Erruption("sea");
}
public void ErruptionAtLand()
{
    Erruption("land");
}
// ...and so on.
```

Option 2: Add a script to the button which says which biome this button is for. Wire the onclick-event of the button to that script:

```
public class EruptionButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public string biomeName;

    public void DoEruption () {
        Eruption(biomeName)
    }
}
```

Option 3: If you don't want to set up the click handling for each button individually, you can have that script take care of this automatically by assigning a newly created anonymous method as a click handler to the button on the same game object:

```
[@RequireComponent(typeof (UnityEngine.UI.Button))]
public class EruptionButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public string biomeName;

    void Start () {
        UnityEngine.UI.Button button = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => { Eruption(biomeName); } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Unity 2018.3, a button can pass values to the methods which handle its click events. In order to do that, the function must take exactly one parameter and that parameter must be a string, int, float or bool:

[image: Unity Button with parameter]

Comment: Are you sure this is specific to 2018+? It looks like it works going back as far as Unity 5 (ca. 2015)

Comment: @DMGregory I am pretty sure it wasn't there at least in 2018.1.

Comment: I mean I literally opened up version 5 last night and duplicated this. Unless I'm missing some detail where it looks like it works in the editor, but there's some restriction that prevents its use?